# Утечка ОЗУ в Windows Server

Tags: windows, память, windows-server-2008-r2

Есть сервер HP Proliant DL120 G7 - на нем есть 8 Гб ОЗУ и на нем же крутится Win2k8 R2 std, запущен сервер терминалов. Но есть проблема. За два дня - что-то поедает всю оперативу - лечится только ребутом. Скрины ДЗ и процессов.

[image: диспетчер задач]

[image: диспетчер задач]

[image: монитор ресурсов]

Comment: Тут еще какая закономерность ) Проверить мне её почти ни когда не получается. После перезагрузки, если не трогать, ОЗУ не кушается. Но как только закупускается учетка 1С, где происходть РИБ. Тут пошло поехало. Но проверить это не возможно пока что :( Только в ВСК ни кто не работает.

Comment: Сервак как раз для 1С и брался. И он не нужен оч производительный . В терминале сидит макс 10 юзеров, по идее это + 2,5 гига ОЗУ к 2 виндовым.

Comment: Для shrekКак раз много доков и не открывается! Один журнал , да документ! Для maliusДа, как раз запущен удаленный рабочий стол у всех. если делать 1С  веб приложение отдельно, то почему то подвисает вреия от времени и закрыть получается только через ДЗ.Зато на складе стоит HP MicroServer ) с 4 гигаги ОЗУ и 5 удаленок и все идеально работает сутками.... Вот тут и вывод. либо криво встал 1С с виндой, либо руки у меня кривые :)

Comment: 1С вообще штука кривая.

Comment: Это точно :(

Comment: Потому что у нас файловая база.

Comment: а нажми кнопочку монитор ресурсов и скрин нам)

Comment: Квип на сервер улыбнул, я думаю то твои юзеры нашалили, нельзя давать им волю к рабочему столу, сделай среду запуска, дай им только 1с, нереально многовато жрет сервачок)

Comment: Все ушел, на последок могу посоветовать посмотреть active system console на сервере или что там стоит HP manager...

Comment: @Денис Мельников, если Вам помог ответ - жмакните по галке слева под кулчаком вниз. ![alt text][1](взято из ответа @shaman888)  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/lPQEm.png

Comment: Не совсем понятно, о чем вопрос. Понятия "утечки оперативной памяти" в виртуальной ОС не существует, если только процесс специально не выделяет невыгружаемые страницы. Рабочие наборы нескольких экземпляров 1cv8 заняли всю оперативную память - ну так может это и нормально? На основе чего сделаны подозрения об утечке?

Comment: @AnT ого =) 6 лет как бы прошло с вопроса =) давно не актуально =)

Answer (score 1):

Ну что тут можно сказать, либо ограничьте пользователей на использование ресурсов сервера, либо подключений к 1Су.

Либо добавить оперативы на сервак, раз уж так долбите 1С.

Можно вообще 1С на отдельный сервак - если вы так сильно и массово общаетесь с 1С

Comment: Как бы слишком жирно разрастается память. Скорее всего что юзвери открывают один коннект к 1С но открывают много доков вот и память кушается.

Comment: Монитор ресурсов - скрин добавил.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант - задать ограничение длительности активного/бездействующего/отключенного сеанса. Правда, если пользователи не приучены выходить из 1С, чревато регулярной индексацией базы...